# Is there a way to evaluate an if condition only once at runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, c++17, runtime

Hello fellow C++ programmers !

You probably know about `if constexpr` that basically lets the compiler evaluate if statements at compile time, leading to better runtime performances as the compiler would basically replace the if statements by their content.
So from the following code :

```cpp
void foo()
{
    if constexpr (true)
    {
        // Do stuff;
    }
}
```

The compiler would convert it to :

```cpp
void foo()
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve kind of the same logic at runtime : at a given time, an if statement could be evaluated only once in its scope and then would be completely skipped aftewards (since the condition value would remain the same).

Here is an example where it would be useful :

```cpp
// MyClass.h
#pragma once

#include <vector>

class MyOtherClass;

class MyClass
{
public:
    void AddOtherClass(MyOtherClass& otherClass) { m_OtherClasses.push_back(otherClass); }
    
    void Update();
    void SomeMethod();
    void SomeOtherMethod();

private:
    enum UpdateMode
    {
        UpdateMode_None = 0x0,
        UpdateMode_Stuff = 0x1,
        UpdateMode_SomeOtherStuff = 0x2,
        UpdateMode_YetOtherStuff = 0x4,
    };

    std::vector<MyOtherClass> m_OtherClasses;
    UpdateMode m_UpdateMode { UpdateMode_None };
};

// MyOtherClass.h
#pragma once

class MyOtherClass
{
public:
    void UpdateStuff() {}
    void UpdateSomeOtherStuff() {}
    void UpdateYetOtherStuff() {}
};

// MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

#include "MyOtherClass.h"

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    // ...
    m_UpdateMode |= UpdateMode_Stuff;
    m_UpdateMode |= UpdateMode_SomeOtherStuff;
    // ...
}

void MyClass::SomeOtherMethod()
{
    // ...
    m_UpdateMode |= UpdateMode_YetOtherStuff;
    // ...
}

void MyClass::Update()
{
    for (MyOtherClass& otherClass : m_OtherClasses)
    {
        if ((m_UpdateMode & UpdateMode_Stuff) != 0)
        {
            otherClass.UpdateStuff();
        }
        if (((m_UpdateMode & UpdateMode_SomeOtherStuff)) != 0)
        {
            otherClass.UpdateSomeOtherStuff();
        }
        if (((m_UpdateMode & UpdateMode_YetOtherStuff)) != 0)
        {
            otherClass.UpdateYetOtherStuff();
        }
    }

    m_UpdateMode = UpdateMode_None;
}

// main.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "MyOtherClass.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    MyOtherClass otherClass;
    
    myClass.AddOtherClass(otherClass);
    // ... Feed MyClass vector even more ...

    myClass.SomeMethod();
    // ...
    myClass.Update();
    myClass.SomeOtherMethod();
    // ...
}
```

As you can see in `MyClass::Update()` method, for each vector element, we would evaluate all 3 if statements while each of them would always yield the same result on each iteration.
In real scenarios, we might have even more if statements to evaluate and we might be processing a huge amount of elements.
I couldn't find any way to achieve that or any resources about this specific thing so I'm wondering if it is even possible or if it makes any sense.

I tried using `constexpr` functions / 'constexpr' variables but since the statements values are determined at runtime, it (of course) didn't compile.
I also tried using 'if constexpr' but here again : it didn't compile for the same reason.
I also tried evaluating the statements once before the for loop, but the if block still gets hit at runtime

Cheers !

Comment: Are you asking about a local static variable?

Comment: No because it wouldn't fix the "issue" : the if statements would still be evaluated each time and I don't need to reuse those variables values between distinct 'MyClass::Update()' calls

Comment: Move your code blocks into 2 functions/lambdas, evaluate a static pointer conditionally and call a referenced function/lambda further w/o checking the condition. In other words, store a pointer `(MyOtherClass::*p)() = &MyOtherClass::UpdateStuff;` or other method and call it in the loop.

Comment: Your `if` conditions are very lightweight, so I don't think in practise you could do much better than this. Of course given `n` if statements you could write `2^n` functions and just pick the appropriate one, but that is crazy. Also again given `n` if statements you could store `n` function pointers, which point either to a one of your if statement blocks or to a do nothing function. Technically that means you calculate each if statement condition once, but I think it would be slower than your existing code (as well as more complex).

Comment: @Merihem - Like john says, the  tests are *very* lightweight - we are talkning nanoseconds to mask an integer. On common processors you also have a hardware branch predictor that will quickly learn the most common result, and make that jump faster. So what else is there to optimize? Probably not much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat tangential answer, but yes! You can use an intermediate compilation. An example of this is what is done by SYCL. the GPU programming framework for C++. SYCL uses an intermediate representation (SPIRV) that you compile to at compile time. This is then compiled at runtime for a specific device. [More information about this here](https://intel.github.io/llvm-docs/design/CompilerAndRuntimeDesign.html).

The point is that the sycl standard provides something called [specialisation constants](https://intel.github.io/llvm-docs/design/CompilerAndRuntimeDesign.html) which allow you to inject run time parameters into your compile time program. For example:

```
class specialized_kernel;

// const static identifier of specialization constant
const static sycl::specialization_id<bool> b;

...

  sycl::queue queue;
  queue.submit([&](auto &cgh) {

      // Set value of specialization constant.
      cgh.template set_specialization_constant<b>(get_runtime_value());

      // Runtime builds the kernel with specialization constant
      // replaced by the literal value provided in the preceding
      // call of `set_specialization_constant<value_id>`
      cgh.template single_task(
          [=](sycl::kernel_handler kh) {
            constexpr bool is_set = kh.get_specialization_constant<b>();
            if constexpr (is_set) {
               // ...
            }
          });
    });
  }
  queue.wait_and_throw();
```

In this example, the value is very much a "compile time constant" even though you run it at runtime. In your example, it is a bit more complex, but still possible to set up. Whether this is faster than just 1 more branch condition in each run is debatable though. You have significant cost to compile on the first run of the program and subsequent kernel launch times may be longer than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You might create the function template, and dispatch according to the runtime value:

```
template <UpdateMode mode>
void MyClass::UpdateImpl()
{
    for (MyOtherClass& otherClass : m_OtherClasses)
    {
        if constexpr ((mode & UpdateMode_Stuff) != 0)
        {
            otherClass.UpdateStuff();
        }
        if constexpr (((mode & UpdateMode_SomeOtherStuff)) != 0)
        {
            otherClass.UpdateSomeOtherStuff();
        }
        if constexpr (((m_UpdateMode & UpdateMode_YetOtherStuff)) != 0)
        {
            otherClass.UpdateYetOtherStuff();
        }
    }
    m_UpdateMode = UpdateMode_None;
}

template <auto x>
using IC = std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x>;

// Might even be done generic with std::index_sequence
std::variant<IC<UpdateMode(0)>, IC<UpdateMode(1)>, IC<UpdateMode(2)>, IC<UpdateMode(3)>, IC<UpdateMode(4)>, IC<UpdateMode(5)>, IC<UpdateMode(6)>, IC<UpdateMode(7)>>
MyClass::asConstMode(UpdateMode mode) const
{
    switch (mode) {
        case UpdateMode(0): return IC<UpdateMode(0)>{};
        case UpdateMode(1): return IC<UpdateMode(1)>{};
        case UpdateMode(2): return IC<UpdateMode(2)>{};
        case UpdateMode(3): return IC<UpdateMode(3)>{};
        case UpdateMode(4): return IC<UpdateMode(4)>{};
        case UpdateMode(5): return IC<UpdateMode(5)>{};
        case UpdateMode(6): return IC<UpdateMode(6)>{};
        case UpdateMode(7): return IC<UpdateMode(7)>{};
    }
}

void MyClass::Update()
{
    std::visit([]<UpdateMode mode>(IC<mode>){ UpdateImpl<mode>(); }, asConstMode(m_UpdateMode));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void MyClass::Update() {
    auto const updateMode = m_UpdateMode;
    for (MyOtherClass& otherClass : m_OtherClasses) {
        if ((updateMode & UpdateMode_Stuff) != 0) {
            otherClass.UpdateStuff();
        }
        if ((updateMode & UpdateMode_SomeOtherStuff) != 0) {
            otherClass.UpdateSomeOtherStuff();
        }
        if ((updateMode & UpdateMode_YetOtherStuff) != 0) {
            otherClass.UpdateYetOtherStuff();
        }
    }
    m_UpdateMode = UpdateMode_None;
}
```

Store `m_UpdateMode` in a local variable so the compiler can be sure that it is not modified in the loop. Then let the optimizer figure out the rest. It *may* be faster to evaluate the conditions outside of the loop, basically turning your code into this:

```
if ((updateMode & UpdateMode_Stuff) != 0 && 
    (updateMode & UpdateMode_SomeOtherStuff) != 0) {
    for (MyOtherClass& otherClass : m_OtherClasses) {
        otherClass.UpdateStuff();
        otherClass.UpdateOtherStuff();
    }
}
if ((updateMode & UpdateMode_Stuff) != 0 && 
    (updateMode & UpdateMode_SomeOtherStuff) == 0) {
    for (MyOtherClass& otherClass : m_OtherClasses) {
        otherClass.UpdateStuff();
    }
}
if ((updateMode & UpdateMode_Stuff) == 0 && 
    (updateMode & UpdateMode_SomeOtherStuff) != 0) {
    for (MyOtherClass& otherClass : m_OtherClasses) {
        otherClass.UpdateOtherStuff();        
    }
}
// ...
```

But this also introduces code bloat. You end up with 2^N (**exponentially many**) seperate loops where N is the number of `if` statements in the original loop. The resulting larger binary size might make your slower in the end.

Modern C++ compilers are heavily optimized to analyze this kind of stuff. They can turn the first version (conditions in the loop) into the second version (conditions outside of the loop), if they conclude that it would make your code faster. So unless you're *really sure* that one of the two alternatives is faster (because you have measured it), just go with the first approach and let the compiler make a decision.

Also note that modern CPUs have branch predictors, so if you have a condition in a loop that is always the same, it will be predicted by the CPU with little to no overhead.

Comment: That being said, I once wrote a [little library](https://github.com/chrysante/Utility/blob/main/include/utl/dynamic_dispatch.hpp) to transform these kind of loops for me and used it [here](https://github.com/chrysante/Worldmachine/blob/master/Worldmachine/BuiltinNodes/VoronoiNode.cpp#L184). I think the code is quite ugly though and don't recommend anyone to use it.